# Client send message but Server dont receive message until client ends program

Tags: c++, aes, crypto++

```
    do{

        /// send msgs
        cout << "Client: ";
        cin.getline(clientMSG, 1024, '\n');

        if(strcmp(clientMSG, "quit") == 0){

            StringSource msgEncryptor(clientMSG, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encrypt, new StringSink(encryptMSG)));
            StringSource encryptEncode(encryptMSG, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encodeMSG)));

            memset(clientSEND, '\0', 3000);
            copy(encodeMSG.begin(), encodeMSG.end(), clientSEND);

            send(sock, clientSEND, strlen(clientSEND), 0);

            break;
        }

        StringSource msgEncryptor(clientMSG, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encrypt, new StringSink(encryptMSG)));
        StringSource encryptEncode(encryptMSG, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encodeMSG)));

        memset(clientSEND, '\0', 3000);
        copy(encodeMSG.begin(), encodeMSG.end(), clientSEND);

        send(sock, clientSEND, strlen(clientSEND), 0);

        /** ------------------------------------------------ **/

        /// receive msgs
        memset(clientRECV, '\0', 3000);
        valread = read(sock, clientRECV, 3000);

        StringSource encryptDecode(clientRECV, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(decodeMSG)));
        StringSource msgDecryptor(decodeMSG, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decrypt, new StringSink(decryptMSG)));

        cout << "Server: " << decryptMSG << endl;





    }while(1);
```

Above is the client program

```
do{

        /// receive msgs

        memset(serverRECV, '\0', 3000);
        valread = read(new_socket, serverRECV, 3000);

        StringSource encryptDecode(serverRECV, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(decodeMSG)));
        StringSource msgDecryptor(decodeMSG, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decrypt, new StringSink(decryptMSG)));

        if(decryptMSG == "quit"){
            cout << "Client disconnected!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Client: " << decryptMSG << endl;

        /** ------------------------------------------------------------------------ **/

        /// send msgs

        cout << "Server: ";
        cin.getline(serverMSG, 1024, '\n');

        if(strcmp(serverMSG, "quit") == 0){
            StringSource msgEncryptor(serverMSG, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encrypt, new StringSink(encryptMSG)));
            StringSource encryptEncode(encryptMSG, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encodeMSG)));

            memset(serverSEND, '\0', 3000);
            copy(encodeMSG.begin(), encodeMSG.end(), serverSEND);

            send(new_socket, serverSEND, strlen(serverSEND), 0);

            break;
        }

        StringSource msgEncryptor(serverMSG, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encrypt, new StringSink(encryptMSG)));
        StringSource encryptEncode(encryptMSG, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encodeMSG)));

        memset(serverSEND, '\0', 3000);
        copy(encodeMSG.begin(), encodeMSG.end(), serverSEND);

        send(new_socket, serverSEND, strlen(serverSEND), 0);

        cin.clear();
        memset(serverMSG, '\0', 3000);
    }while(1);
```

this one is the server.

I'm trying to code some socket program and i suddenly faced this issue where when the client sends a message, the server doesn't display it until i force end the program.

The program is supposed to start with the client entering a message then encrypting the message and sending it to the server. Then, the server will decrypt it and display the message. But i don't understand why is it not displaying the message only when i end the program it displays...

Am i using the wrong way of send/read? I'm pretty sure it's not the encrypt/decrypt problem because i see the message at the server side when i end the program at the client side.

Comment: Did you write a program that worked _without_ encryption?

Comment: There's a lot of information missing, like the communication details. You should probably get your client/server working with plain text messages. Once things work with plain text messages then move on to encrypted messages. I think this is what Neil is suggesting. Also see [how to write a tcp client and server](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+a+tcp+client+and+server). If the client and server are running on the same machine then checkout a [message queue](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you didn't setup your socket as non-blocking, but that line on server-side :

```
valread = read(new_socket, serverRECV, 3000);
```

... is trying to read 3000 bytes from the socket. The read() function blocks the current thread until all data have been read from the descriptor. Closing the program aborts read() and the rest of the code is executed at this time.

With your code, make sure that the client sends 3000 bytes if you wish your server to process it.

If you wish to perform non-blocking read, you should set your socket accordingly :

```
int flags = fcntl(new_socket, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(new_socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Beware, thought, that you'll need to check a lot of return values for read(), and create a a logic where you read from the socket until you received the correct amount of bytes.

Comment: @adam-chua Did that answer your question?